# Different call sequence of the Activity lifecycle callbacks while opening app from the push

Tags: android, android-activity, android-push-notification

I'm seeing a strange behavior while open app from the push notification.
There are 2 cases:
1) the app is in the background and device is unlocked;
2) the app is in the background and device is locked.

When device receives push notification I click on it, my app starts (device screen is being unlocked if needed) and I see the following sequence of the **Activity** lifecycle callbacks:
1) in the 1st case - **onResume** is called once;
2) in the 2nd case - **onResume** -> **onPause** -> **onResume**.

I'm interested in 2nd case. The second **onResume**'s call I'm understanding.

Why Android calls **onPause**'s callback?
Is it default behavior or problem in my app settings (for example specific launchMode in my **Activity**)?
Anybody can help me understand the 2nd case and how to avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"?

Comment: @IvanWooll I mean that screen is off and blocked by android system (I press power button for block device).

Comment: so you mean 'locked'

Comment: `"how to avoid it`" don't use `onPause` and `onResume` unless you're writing a Camera app?

Comment: @MartinPfeffer yes, sorry for my English..

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I need those callbacks or alternatives for understanding current state of the app

Comment: Oh I see. Well there is most likely a system level dialog hovering over your app for some reason.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce When I lock screen onPause is called, then I unlock screen and onResume is called once as in the 1st case. But when I unlock screen by click on the push notification I see the 2nd case (onResume - onPause - onResume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many related questions on Stackoverflow about `onResume()` and `onPause()` being called multiple times in combination with use of the lock screen. This seems to be a common problem. In general, `onPause()` and `onResume()` can be called many times, also in quick succession and your app needs to be robust enough to handle that.

See:

- [Android Activity lifecycle and locking/unlocking device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205049/android-activity-lifecycle-and-locking-unlocking-device)
- [onResume being called over and over while phone screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731285/onresume-being-called-over-and-over-while-phone-screen-is-locked)
- [How to prevent or handle onResume being called when phone screen is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000261/how-to-prevent-or-handle-onresume-being-called-when-phone-screen-is-locked)
- [Locking screen of Android phone results in several subsequent onPause/onResume events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290018/locking-screen-of-android-phone-results-in-several-subsequent-onpause-onresume-e)
- [Lock screen triggers application lifecycle events of different activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652630/lock-screen-triggers-application-lifecycle-events-of-different-activity)